# Tomcat: java.io.IOException : Destination "xxx" directory cannot be created"

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, tomcat7

I would like to do projects backup from one location to another location in network.this sample application has been written in struts.
This was achieved by using `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils`.

My problem here is, when I ran this application in netbeans 6.9 IDE tomcat server its working fine, but when I tried to run this application in apache tomcat 7.0 server by deploying this application WAR file, I get exception like

```
java.io.IOException : Destination "xxx" directory cannot be created"
```

this destination path is another machine in our local network.

I assume some kind of netbeans IDE options which are enabling tomcat server to copy folder to a destination directory when I ran it in netbeans tomcat.

where as, if I run this application in tomcat server some kind of tomcat file permissions are blocking.

Both source and destination are shared folders.

Comment: [Kasim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154387/backup-of-projects-on-daily-basis-to-a-backup-server), is that you?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to setup a permission (in your case *File Permission*) for your webapplication as Tomcat runs a Security Manager, for security precautions. See [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/security-manager-howto.html) for configuration.